# creating a file in bash, how do I utilize 2>/dev/null in case it is not possible to create?

Tags: bash

I am creating a script which will calculate some different information about directories.  I have to give the option to the user to create a file.  Many different file checks are done, but one in particular is giving me grief:

if the file name is checked and does not exist, the script is to try to create it.  If the creation fails, the user is to be notified that it couldn't be created.

So I have a variable (file) which is the name the user has given to the file he wishes to create.  I then use:

```
echo -n "Creating the file: '$file'"
touch "$file"
if [ -e "$file" ]; then
  echo "..........File created"
  else echo"...........Creation failed"
fi
```

Does the >2/dev/null go after the touch line?  What would be the proper syntax to suppress the error message, and only display Creating the file:(file).........Creation failed?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `2>` and not `>2` to redirect standard error.

```
touch "$file" 2> /dev/null
```

But even with this change your script has a bug:

Suppose the `touch` fails because the file exists but you do not have permission to touch it. Next you check if the file exists using the `-e` check which returns `true` and you print `File created` which is incorrect.

To fix this you need to check the return value of `touch` command as:

```
if  touch "$file" 2> /dev/null ; then
echo "..........File created"
else
echo "..........File failed"
```

Comment: damn it, I was missing the space after >.  what a bonehead.  Thanks for the fresh eyes

Comment: I just tried it, with touch "$file"(space)2>(space(andnospace))/dev/null  and an error message still appears on the screen

Comment: That kicks it!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You actually want:

```
touch "$file" 2> /dev/null
```

(note `2>` rather than `>2`)

Comment: As I said in response to the other poster (sorry to be redundant), I have tried it this way, and the error still appears on the screen,  it reads "Creating the filename: '(filename)'touch: cannot touch `(filename)': Permission denied
........Failed

Comment: Unit, I can't replicate your results. For example, touch /bin/bash 2>/dev/null produces no output.

Comment: @unit: please post your *exact* code - you probably have a typo or some other trivial issue...